# PHP: Creating csv file if data text contains "," data will be splitted into parts and put it in other column?

Tags: php, csv

I got problems in creating a csv file because if my data contains `,` it will be splitted into parts and put it in other columns that destroys my csv file.

Here is the sample output:

[Sample output link](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/3034/39013281.png)

As what you can see the first row in `TITLE` column should have this data `"Acer Aspire AS5250-0639 15.5" Laptop (1.65 GHz AMD Dual-Core Processor E-450, 4 GB RAM, 500 GB Hard Drive, DVD+/-RW Optical Drive, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit)"` starting in `4 GB RAM` it is splitted and put it in other columns because before it it has `,` and more.

As of now here is my PHP script:

```
    <?php
include 'database.php';
$db = new database();

$data = $db->exportdatabase();

$out = '';
$out .= 'GSEQ,BRAND,TITLE,SIMAGE,SPRICE,WEIG,DIMENSIONS,ASIN,CATEGORYNAME,MODELNO';
$out .="\n";

foreach($data as $items){
    $out .=' '.$items['GSEQ'].', '.$items['BRAND'].', '.$items['TITLE'].', '.$items['SIMAGE'].', '.$items['SPRICE'].', '.$items['WEIG'].', '.$items['DIMENSIONS'].' 
    '.$items['ASIN'].', '.$items['CATEGORYNAME'].', '.$items['MODELNO'].'
    ';
    $out .="\n"; 
    //var_dump($items);
}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/csv") ;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Data.csv");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $out;
exit;   
?>
```

How can I possibly fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters I would stop trying to do something yourself that PHP can do for you. Use fputcsv instead of doing it yourself: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php. This method also deals with escaping your delimiter ( your comma ).

On top of that.. dont use ',' as your csv seperator. You are probably better off using '|' as a seperater, since that character is way less common.

Comment: If you minvote, atleast have the decency to explain -why- in a comment. As far as I can tell my answer deals with the comma problem perfectly.

Comment: I tried to change the separator to '|' but the output gets worst :\

Comment: @MekeniKine - please be a little more specific when you state your problems, what does "output gets worse" actually mean? What does your output look like?

Comment: If you change your seperator to '|' you will also have to change the seperator in the application where you are trying to load the file. Ie. if you open the file in Excel, you also have to tell excel to use | as a column seperator.

Comment: Still feel you should use fputcsv, but I added another answer that should also fix your problem, though it being a more ugly method.

Comment: Yeah!I tried it easy to use but got problem i don't know how to put the fields in my situation like the fields in my question..

Answer (score 0):

One method is to wrap each field using quotes (")

Another is to replace the troublesome "," with another character using str_replace.